# Best Way to Remove Malware and Recover Files

Tags: virus, file-recovery, virus-removal

So a family member's laptop got hit with a nasty virus which has made the device unusable including being unable to run a virus scan. The computeri simply freezes right after completing the boot up process. I was able to boot up from a live Linux USB stick which gave access to the files in the harddrive.  So what is the best approach to run a virus scan and recover the files in question. (I'm thinking quarantining the recovered files in dedicated USB stick.)

The laptop is running Windows 10 x64

**Edit:** So now there is also partial disk failure. Said family member took the laptop to a repair shop (without my knowledge) to get a diagnostic. Not sure if the two events are related. Also, I was able to recover the import files to a dedicated USB stick

Comment: You need to boot an external, anti-virus recovery disc. Most AV software allows you to create this. You should make it unwritable (CD-R, DVD-R or SD card in USB adapter with write-protect switch).

Comment: Have you tried booting into safe mode? In windows ten you can open the start menu, press the power button and click restart WHILE HOLDING shift.  Most of the time if malware is bogging a system down you will have a few seconds after boot before it completely locks in which you could restart it into safe mode. If you can pull that off you will most likely be able to run your Anti-Virus from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a bootable Hirens 15.6 USB or Disk with another working machine, within Hirens 15.6 there are a number of antivirus tools such as SuperAntiSpyware, Spybot Search & Destroy, MalwareBytes etc...

All of these programs have worked wonders for me in the past.

Comment: I was looking at hirens boot CD and it has loots if tools. I'm assuming these tools come bundled, so was the minimum size required for a USB stick?

Comment: Hirens has a whole load of features outside of Anti-Virus, you should be looking to download Hirens in the form of an ISO files in which you will need to create a bootable USB from it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Lots of nifty tools, tho

Answer (score 0):

A Linux Live CD would be best to recover files. To get rid of the virus, you can try HBCD as suggested, and another way would be to create a Windows To Go USB drive and install a full fledged antivirus, in case HBCD doesn't support these.